# barplot in a factor variable with ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a factor variable (chest) with 4 levels:

```
  1   2   3   4 
 23  49  84 143
```

I want to create a barplot. In the normal way I have this and it works:

```
barplot(summary(chest))
```

I wanted to do a more elaborate barplot using ggplot

```
ggplot(data=chest, aes(x="Chest_pain")) +
    geom_bar( fill="steelblue")+
    geom_text(aes(label=len), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
    theme_minimal()
```

I got 'Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a factor.'

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we can reproduce your data like this:

```r
chest <- factor(rep(1:4, times = c(23, 49, 84, 143)))
```

So that we have

```r
summary(chest)
#>   1   2   3   4 
#>  23  49  84 143
```

and can get a base R bar plot with your code as follows:

```r
barplot(summary(chest))
```

[image]

To get a ggplot we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = chest)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = stat(count)), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Interesting - I always thought ggplot needed at least one data frame, even if empty, e.g. data = data.frame(). Would have been nice to add some explanation to what you have done here.

Comment: @tjebo I would rephrase this to `ggplot works very well with data frames/tibbles`. If you check the `geom_*()` documentation, you will always see `data = NULL` (by default). The mapping of x-y-aesthetics requires a vector. You can emulate this by leaving data blank (aka using data = NULL) or set it to an arbitrary dataframe, AND then supply `aes( x =df$vec1 or vec1, y = df$vec2`. The benefit of using a data frame as input data structure is that you do not have to use `df$` to pull the vectors, ggplot will recognise the variable/column.